# arrows crossing over nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-trees

I have drawn a tree by tikz package, but the arrows are crossing over nodes. is there any switch to prevent this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=0.75cm}]
\graph [tree layout, grow=down, fresh nodes, level distance=2cm, sibling distance=0.5cm]
   {
         0x01  -> {
                   0x10  -> { 0x01 }, 
                   0x19  -> { 0x01 },
                   0x1a  -> {  0x01 , 0x11 ,  0x18 ,  0x1a ,  0x1b  },
                   0x1b  -> {  0x01 , 0x11 ,  0x18 ,  0x1a ,  0x1b  },
                   0x85  -> { 0x01 },
                   0x87  -> { 0x01 },
                   0x8d  -> { 0x01 },
                   0x8f  -> { 0x01 },
                   0xa3  -> { 0x01 },
                   0xaf  -> { 0x01 }
                }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only reordering of nodes and using a `\footnotesize` font can achieve this. The modified code is like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=0.75cm,inner sep=0in}]\footnotesize 

\graph [tree layout, grow=down, fresh nodes, level distance=2cm, sibling distance=0.5cm]
   {
         0x01  -> {0x1a  -> { 0x01 , 0x11 ,  0x18 ,  0x1a ,  0x1b  },
                   0x10  -> { 0x01 }, 
                   0x19  -> { 0x01 },
                   0x85  -> { 0x01 },
                   0x87  -> { 0x01 },
                   0x8d  -> { 0x01 },
                   0x8f  -> { 0x01 },
                   0xa3  -> { 0x01 },
                   0xaf  -> { 0x01 },
                   0x1b  -> { 0x01 , 0x11 ,  0x18 ,  0x1a ,  0x1b  }
                }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with `LuaLaTeX` gives:

.... I will upload the image in a while. The site is not uploading at the moment. I apologize..

Umm.. here it is:

[image]